# Vue test watcher change but code inside not response

Tags: vue.js, testing, watch

I'm stuck in this situation where I have a getters from Vuex Store, and whenever that getter change (new value update), the local state data(the 'list') should be reassign .
[This is my component, which has 'list' in data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uttP3.png)

And here is my test [Successfully change the getSkills to the getSkillsMock, but there is no response from list, list is still an []](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTkeY.png)

Answer (score 0):

> You need to set deep to true when watching an array or object so that
>   Vue knows that it should watch the nested data for changes.

```
watch: {
 getSkills: {
  handler () {
   this.list = this.getSkills.map(items => {
    return { value: items.id, label: items.name }
   })
  },
  deep: true
 }
}
```

Comment: Also, to check if Vue is able to watch a property, the handler fn takes two params: `handler (newValue, oldValue)`, you can console both to check if the property is being watched.